# Django admin models not showing in production

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've put my django project into production. Every time a add an admin model it does not update and show on my admin panel. The migrations and collectstatic commands are all going through fine.
I have tried to source a fix but I just can't get it to work. Works completely fine in local server.

Here is my code although:

models.py

```
class PostImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False, upload_to="images", default="default.png")
    image_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, default="")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.image_title
        

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    blog_article = QuillField(null=True, blank=True)
    blog_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images", default="default.png")
    blog_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title

class EnterImage(models.Model):
    enter_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images", default="default.png")
    enter_image_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, default="")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.enter_image_title
        
class QuillPost(models.Model):
    content = QuillField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
        
class AboutMe(models.Model):
    about_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images", default="default.png")
    about_image_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, default="")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.about_image_title
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('martinhensonphotography.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . models import PostImage, EnterImage, BlogPost, QuillPost, AboutMe

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(PostImage)
admin.site.register(BlogPost)
admin.site.register(EnterImage)
admin.site.register(QuillPost)
admin.site.register(AboutMe)
```

APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'martinhensonphotography.apps.MartinhensonphotographyConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_quill',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to give whatever user you are using in production permission to view / list the new models in your admin view